# Colon for 'because' omission?

Tags: punctuation

Colon or semicolon when *because* is omitted from a sentence e.g.,

> I am sorry I disturbed you (;) (:) *(because)* it looked like you were having a lot of fun there.

*Because* explains and clarifies a preceding clause so would it be correct to use a colon preceding the explanatory clause if *because* is omitted?

Alternatively, *because* can be replaced by *for*, which is a coordinating conjunction and would correctly be punctuated with a semicolon.

> I am sorry I disturbed you, for it looked like you were having a lot of fun there.
>
> I am sorry I disturbed you; it looked like you were having a lot of fun there.

*For* is of course reasonably archaic but is useful sometimes for grammatical clarity.

And if anyone wants to comment on the *that* omission and comma replacement, I'd be very happy.

I am sorry *(that)*(,) I disturbed you because it looked like you were having a lot of fun there.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot here.

Okay...

For your first question, a semicolon is best fitting. Using a colon makes for a much more rigid construction and wholly levies blame onto yourself for the change in the recipient's mood. The semicolon allows a looser connection between the decline in the mood of the recipient and the actions you took to (potentially) induce unhappiness. A colon forges a very solid link between two clauses.

You can't use a comma in your last sentence. That would create a comma splice as there are two main clauses either side of it. A semicolon would work here. You can omit "that" because we often cut out words that add no meaning to a sentence. "That" merely serves as a conjunction which sets up a clause that expresses some reason [for you being sorry].